# Match files against MANIFEST of patterns

Tags: bash, shell, unix, gitlab-ci

I want to check if some files match the patterns declared in a manifest file. So, for example, the following files

```
A_cycles.pdf
A_filter_passed_vs_occupied.pdf
A_grouped_cycle.csv
A_grouped_lane.csv
A_grouped_lane_cycle.csv
A_metadata.csv
A_percent_q30.pdf
A_raw.csv
seqrun_A.json
```

should be checked against this MANIFEST

```
*_grouped_cycle.csv
*_grouped_lane.csv
*_grouped_lane_cycle.csv
*_metadata.csv
*_raw.csv
seqrun_*.json
```

This is my code:

```
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    # Modify the pattern to match filenames without needing to escape dot characters
    modified_pattern="${pattern//./[.]}"
    # Convert the modified pattern to a regular expression
    regex_pattern="^${modified_pattern//\*/.*}"
    # Check if the filename matches the pattern using regular expressions
    if [[ "$filename1" =~ $regex_pattern ]]; then
        included=true
        echo "Filename $(basename "$filename1") matched pattern $pattern in MANIFEST"
        break
    fi
done < <(grep -v '^#' "$MANIFEST_FILE")
```

and this is the output:

```
Filename A_grouped_cycle.csv matched pattern *_grouped_cycle.csv in MANIFEST
Filename A_grouped_lane.csv matched pattern *_grouped_lane.csv in MANIFEST
Filename A_grouped_lane_cycle.csv matched pattern *_grouped_lane_cycle.csv in MANIFEST
Filename A_metadata.csv matched pattern *_metadata.csv in MANIFEST
Filename A_raw.csv matched pattern *_raw.csv in MANIFEST
```

Is almost working but I don't know why is not matching `seqrun_A.json` with `seqrun_*.json`.

I tried several approaches but without success. This approach should work/match with any kind of pattern declared in the MANIFEST file, in that similar way (basically using *).

Btw, this is included in a Gitlab CI Job

Comment: Never just use the word "pattern" when talking about pattern matching - say literal string, regexp, or globbing pattern, whichever type of "pattern matching" it is you're trying to do, for your own clarity and ours. Does your manifest file contain literal strings, regexps, or globbing patterns? Is that the type of matching you want to do against your file names (you seem to be trying to convert them to regexps but if they're globbing patterns why not do a glob match)? Do you want to do full or partial matching (does `the` match `then`)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide all of the missing information on the kind of pattern matching you want to do so we can help you. Oh, and your code does `grep -v '^#' "$MANIFEST_FILE"` which suggest you have some lines in your manifest that contain `#`s that you want to ignore so make sure your example includes such lines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the MANIFEST contains glob patterns.

Unquoted expansion undergo word splitting and filename expansion. The lazy answer would be just to:

```
shopt -s nullglob
echo $(cat MANIFEST)
```

That would result in word splitting. Using bash, we would use `compgen -G` to expand glob to the list of files.

```
readarray -t patterns <MANIFEST
compgen -G "${patterns[@]}"
```

Comment: Can't use compgen or any other external inside my CI. ANy other idea?

Comment: I do not understand "external". compgen is a builtin bash command. If you have bash, you have compgen. You can run `xargs bash -c 'compgen -G "$@"' -- < MANIFEST` . There is also python.

Answer (score 0):

This presumes to work:

```
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    # Check if the filename matches the pattern using fnmatch
    if [[ "$(basename "$filename1")" == $pattern ]]; then
        included=true
        echo "Filename $(basename "$filename1") matched pattern $pattern in MANIFEST"
        break
    fi
done < <(grep -v '^#' "$MANIFEST_FILE")
```

Simply by using "==" but I don't understand why. Does UNIX automatically compares string with globs?

**UPDATE/EXPLANATION**

The `==` operator in Bash's conditional expressions `([[ ... ]])` supports pattern matching, including glob patterns. This is not native to Unix but is a feature provided by Bash itself.

When you use `==` within `[[ ... ]]`, Bash treats the right-hand side of the comparison as a pattern if it contains wildcard characters like `*` or `?`. This behavior allows you to perform pattern matching directly in conditional expressions without needing additional commands or functions.

In your case, when you compare `$(basename "$filename1")` with `$pattern` using `==`, Bash recognizes `$pattern` as a *glob pattern* due to the presence of the `*` character, and it performs pattern matching accordingly. This allows you to match filenames against glob patterns directly in your script without needing to resort to external tools or functions.

Answer (score 0):

I [have some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146721/match-files-against-manifest-of-patterns/78147072#comment137770182_78146721) but this MAY be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

readarray -t glob_pats < manifest_globs.txt

for filename; do
    for glob_pat in "${glob_pats[@]}"; do
        if [[ $filename == $glob_pat ]]; then
            echo "$filename matched $glob_pat"
        fi
    done
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh A_cycles.pdf A_filter_passed_vs_occupied.pdf A_grouped_cycle.csv A_grouped_lane.csv A_grouped_lane_cycle.csv A_metadata.csv A_percent_q30.pdf A_raw.csv seqrun_A.json
A_grouped_cycle.csv matched *_grouped_cycle.csv
A_grouped_lane.csv matched *_grouped_lane.csv
A_grouped_lane_cycle.csv matched *_grouped_lane_cycle.csv
A_metadata.csv matched *_metadata.csv
A_raw.csv matched *_raw.csv
seqrun_A.json matched seqrun_*.json
```